# Oracle error : ORA-00905: Missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

Excuting the line of SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  INTO assignment_20081120 
  FROM assignment ;
```

against a database in oracle to back up a table called assignment gives me the following ORACLE error: 
ORA-00905: Missing keyword

Comment: For those finding this from a Google search like I did, though not the only reason the above fails, I got this error when I declared a variable without specifying its type.

Answer (score 30):

Unless there is a single row in the `ASSIGNMENT` table and `ASSIGNMENT_20081120` is a local PL/SQL variable of type `ASSIGNMENT%ROWTYPE`, this is not what you want.

Assuming you are trying to create a new table and copy the existing data to that new table

```
CREATE TABLE assignment_20081120
AS
SELECT *
  FROM assignment
```

Answer (score 7):

First, I thought:

> "...In Microsoft SQL Server the
>   `SELECT...INTO` automatically creates
>   the new table whereas Oracle seems to
>   require you to manually create it
>   before executing the `SELECT...INTO`
>   statement..."

But after manually generating a table, it still did not work, still showing the "missing keyword" error.

So I gave up this time and solved it by first manually creating the table, then using the "classic" `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO assignment_20081120 SELECT * FROM assignment;
```

Which worked as expected. If anyone come up with an explanaition on how to use the `SELECT...INTO` in a correct way, I would be happy!

Comment: The explanation is simply that `SELECT..INTO` is *PL/SQL* syntax, not SQL - it expects a PL/SQL variable to accept the result of the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use select into inside of a PLSQL block such as below.

```
Declare
  l_variable assignment%rowtype
begin
  select *
  into l_variable
  from assignment;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No record avialable')
  when too_many_rows then
   dbms_output.put_line('Too many rows')
end;
```

This code will only work when there is exactly 1 row in assignment. Usually you will use this kind of code to select a specific row identified by a key number.

```
Declare
  l_variable assignment%rowtype
begin
  select *
  into l_variable
  from assignment
  where ID=<my id number>;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No record avialable')
  when too_many_rows then
   dbms_output.put_line('Too many rows')
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this is not directly related to the OP's exact question but I just found out that using a Oracle reserved word in your query (in my case the alias `IN`) can cause the same error.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_INDEPENTS IN
JOIN TBL_VOTERS VO on IN.VOTERID = VO.VOTERID
```

Or if its in the query itself as a field name

```
 SELECT ..., ...., IN, ..., .... FROM SOMETABLE
```

That would also throw that error. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I just came on this list today!

```sql
CREATE TABLE assignment_20101120 AS SELECT * FROM assignment;
```

Does the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you backup a table in Oracle Database. You try the statement below.

```
CREATE TABLE name_table_bk
AS
SELECT *
  FROM name_table;
```

I am using Oracle Database 12c.